# Lifetime of java httpsession

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

According to http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/cprs_best_practice.html?lang=en

> **Avoid trying to save and reuse the HttpSession object outside of each servlet or JSP file :**
>   The HttpSession object is a function of the HttpRequest (you can get
>   it only through the req.getSession method), and a copy of it is valid
>   only for the life of the service method of the servlet or JSP file.
>   **You cannot cache the HttpSession object and refer to it outside the
>   scope of a servlet or JSP file**.

I don't understand as here it is said the contrary : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/webapp/sessions.html

> Session tracking enables you to track a user's progress **over multiple servlets or HTML pages**

Comment: In the first case a servlet is used in plural form.

Comment: What do you mean by "plural" ?

Comment: servlet = servlets, JSP are servlets, but HTML pages aren't servlets, and Oracle emphasized it.

Comment: There is no conflict. The first refers to a specific session *object*, the second to the session itself.

Answer (score 1):

The one from Oracle is good. If for example you set the session attribute "USER" when the user logs in, the user's session is available across all the pages. The session expires based on the time you configure in your web.xml environment for example when you use Tomcat.
Here is what I found from the doc :
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html

> Provides a way to identify a user across more than one page request or visit to a Web site and to store information about that user.
>   The servlet container uses this interface to create a session between an HTTP client and an HTTP server. The session persists for a specified time period, across more than one connection or page request from the user. A session usually corresponds to one user, who may visit a site many times. The server can maintain a session in many ways such as using cookies or rewriting URLs.

Hope it helps!